# Reading file character-by-character and comparing those characters in C

Tags: c, file, char

I've got a little program that reads through a text file character-by-character and checks if the file contains certain values.

If it finds the letter A next to another letter I want the file to push the second letter to a new line and print the result. For example, if I had the following text file:

ABABAAAB

The printed result would be:

```
A
B
A
B
A
A
A
B
```

Would I need to store the current character being read in a variable say called "prevChar" then record the next character in a variable called "currentChar" then compare them and print the result? Keep doing this for every character?

Comment: yes keep doing this.

Comment: As I understand it, you need to make a decision about whether to insert a newline into the output based on each pair of *two* consecutive characters.  It follows that you must maintain information in memory about two characters at a time.  You do not, however, have to remember anything about characters read prior to the most recent two.  An approach along the lines you describe would be a natural way to implement that.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an idea of what this would look like in C? I'm sure it's trivial, I just can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Take a look at the `read` function in c, it could help you to find an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one `bool` variable, say `boolean newLine = false;`, initialized to `false`. That will be indicator that let you know if last character was A.

```
 boolean newLine = false;
    FILE *fp;
    int c;

    fp = fopen("datafile.txt", "w");

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if (newLine) {
            // Here you put char in new line
            if (c == 'A'){
                newLine = true;
            }
            else {
                newLine = false;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
```